# long COMMIT duration, high I/O wait in postgres 9.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.1

We are observing long COMMIT times in postgres logs and high I/O wait times.
Postgres version PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

iotop shows following output

```
          TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
04:01:25 15676 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37713) idle
04:01:16 15676 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37713) idle
04:01:15 15675 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37712) idle in transaction
04:00:51 15407 be/4 postgres  173.52 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37670) idle
04:02:12 16054 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 96.63 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37740) idle
04:04:11 16578 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s   23.66 K/s  0.00 % 95.39 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37793) idle
04:00:59 15570 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 85.27 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37681) COMMIT
04:02:11 16051 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 80.07 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37737) idle
04:01:23 15660 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s   15.75 K/s  0.00 % 52.99 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37693) idle
04:01:35 15658 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s   39.42 K/s  0.00 % 39.18 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37691) idle in transaction
04:01:59 15734 be/4 postgres 1288.75 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 30.35 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37725) idle
04:01:02 15656 be/4 postgres    7.89 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 30.06 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37689) idle
04:02:28 16064 be/4 postgres 1438.18 K/s   15.72 K/s  0.00 % 23.72 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37752) SELECT
04:03:30 16338 be/4 postgres  433.52 K/s   15.76 K/s  0.00 % 22.59 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37775) idle in transaction
04:01:43 15726 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    7.88 K/s  0.00 % 20.77 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37717) idle
04:01:23 15570 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s   15.75 K/s  0.00 % 19.81 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37681) idle
04:02:51 16284 be/4 postgres  441.56 K/s    7.88 K/s  0.00 % 17.11 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37761) idle
04:03:39 16343 be/4 postgres  497.22 K/s   63.14 K/s  0.00 % 13.77 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37780) idle
04:02:40 16053 be/4 postgres  204.88 K/s   31.52 K/s  0.00 % 11.31 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37739) BIND
04:01:13 15646 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s   47.24 K/s  0.00 % 11.17 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37682) BIND
04:01:13 15660 be/4 postgres   94.49 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 10.80 % postgres: masked masked 10.2.21.22(37693) COMMIT
```

Commit times go up to 60 seconds during peak times.
The issue started a week ago and it appears to happen during first minute of every hour.
There was no change to application.
There are no batch jobs running at that time that can cause this issue.
We have eliminated that by stopping all jobs/crawling processes.

We have used pg_repack to remove bloats from 99% tables.
The slow COMMIT operation is on a table that does not have bloats anymore.

RAID10 configuration is used.
Storage is magnetic EBS.
synchronous commit is on.
Postgres is using fdatasync().
AWS supports claims that storage is healthy.

strace showed bunch of semop calls taking lot of times and only one slow fdatasync call.

```
$ egrep "<[0-9][0-9]\." t.*
t.31944:1479632446.159939 semop(6029370, {{11, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <15.760687>
t.32000:1479632447.872642 semop(6127677, {{0, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <14.095245>
t.32001:1479632444.780242 semop(6094908, {{15, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <17.113239>
t.32151:1479632493.655164 select(8, [3 6 7], NULL, NULL, {60, 0}) = 1 (in [3], left {46, 614240}) <14.339090>
t.32198:1479632451.200194 semop(5963832, {{7, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <11.095583>
t.32200:1479632445.740529 semop(6094908, {{13, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <16.153911>
t.32207:1479632451.329028 semop(6062139, {{7, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <10.970497>
t.32226:1479632446.384585 semop(6029370, {{8, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <15.565608>
t.32289:1479632451.044155 fdatasync(106)        = 0 <10.849081>
t.32289:1479632470.284825 semop(5996601, {{14, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <10.686889>
t.32290:1479632444.608746 semop(5963832, {{8, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <17.284606>
t.32301:1479632445.757671 semop(6127677, {{8, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <16.137046>
t.32302:1479632445.504563 semop(6094908, {{4, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <16.389120>
t.32303:1479632445.889161 semop(6029370, {{6, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <16.005659>
t.32304:1479632446.377368 semop(6062139, {{12, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <15.554953>
t.32305:1479632448.269680 semop(6062139, {{14, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <13.717228>
t.32306:1479632450.465661 semop(5963832, {{3, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <11.783744>
t.32307:1479632448.959793 semop(6062139, {{8, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <13.289375>
t.32308:1479632446.948341 semop(6062139, {{10, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <15.001958>
t.32315:1479632451.534348 semop(6127677, {{12, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <10.765300>
t.32316:1479632450.209942 semop(6094908, {{3, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <12.039340>
t.32317:1479632451.032158 semop(6094908, {{7, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <11.217471>
t.32318:1479632451.088017 semop(5996601, {{12, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <11.161855>
t.32320:1479632452.161327 semop(5963832, {{14, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <10.138437>
t.32321:1479632451.070412 semop(5963832, {{13, -1, 0}}, 1) = 0 <11.179321>
```

pg_test_fsync output is available.

Any other pointers are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you think of anything that changed about week ago? Version upgrades, OS security patch install etc? Or even other seemingly unrelated changes in the application. And although you do not run any batch jobs, is the crontab completely empty in your db server and app server?

Comment: Could you look into a few more things for me - First, if the DB is in RDS - AWS, could you look into its monitoring, and see if anything correlates with the slow commits. RDS gives you a two-week window so you san look back to the previous times as well. If it's not AWS, what does your local monitoring say? Second, what makes you say it seems to happen during the very first minute of every hour? Is it possible that someone else is hitting your DB hourly? If it's not a mission-critical, is there a way for us to test your assumptions with some dummy data? Third - if your logs from the old...

Comment: Third - if your logs from the olden days have not been rotated, could we compare them to the new ones to see if anything pops out. Fourth, do you by any chance have a snapshot, pre-optimization, that you could put onto a test server to see if the odd behaviour is related to the repack? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh RDS is also on the table, but it introduces significant lags for read replicas and we are planning to use two different databases for read and write operations where sync between read and write DB is paramount.

Comment: What do you guys think about this? To get even better DB performance, run master on ephemeral and slave on EBS. If we have to stop instance, we can make slave as master. and then later switch to master on ephemeral.

Comment: Sounds dangerous. You lose mission critical data in case of HW failure on the ephemeral node. If anything, commit new data to permanent storage and then serve read requests from an ephemeral in-memory replica for speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved the issue by making following changes.

1. Moved master DB to [EBS optimized instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html)
2. Backed by SSD
3. Using provisioned IOPS
4. used pg_repack to remove bloats

Comment: Have you found out what actually caused the long commit times?

Comment: it is hard to pinpoint, but our best guess is "noisy neighbor" theory as suggested by @DeepakDeore https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/selecting-aws-storage-for-mongodb-deployments-ephemeral-vs-ebs

Comment: Have you checked the AWS monitoring? It would definitely show the performance drops. CloudWatch monitoring has some really neat stats... :)

Comment: Yes we did. Also opened case with them. According to them everything is healthy. This is what AWS recommended. https://acloud.guru/course/aws-certified-sysops-administrator-associate/discuss/-KAq078dsxNP_VkAnPHz/ec2-database-question